# php - strip same tags as parent tag

Tags: php, preg-replace

how can i strip same tags as parent tag using preg_replace ? 
for example i have a tag called `<strip>` and i want to strip any child tags that are `<strip>` for example 
`<strip><strip>Avoid my tag</strip></strip>` i want that to become like that --> `<strip>Avoid my tag</strip>` i don't know that much about preg_* but thats what i already have:

```
preg_replace_callback(
  '#\<strip\>(.+?)\<\/strip\>#s',
  create_function(
    '$matches',
    'return "<strip>".htmlentities($matches[1])."</strip>";'
  ),
  $content
);
```

this little function will apply htmlentities with everything inside `<strip>` tags and idon't want `<strip>` tag to be repeated inside each other

thanks

Comment: `.+?` stops at first instance of `</strip>`.  You could do `(.+)\<\/strip\>` but that would stop at the last instance (e.g. if there were three of these elements this wouldn't work; also if a second instance wasn't a child). Have you consider using a parser for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: that will also strip siblings of parent `<strip>` tag i only want to strip `<strip>` tags that are child of other `<strip>` tags.. btw thanks for reply and no i havn't used parser

Comment: You should use a parser was the point I was getting at. I was also trying to explain why your regex does what it does; https://regex101.com/r/uI4uF1/1. Try the link provided above about parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont user regex for Html dom, take a look at `DOMXPath` the doc is [HERE](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.domxpath.php)

a shot exemple here :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body/*");
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      //Do your stuff here :) 
      echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }
}
```

If it's some XML take a look at `SimpleXMLElement` [HERE](http://php.net/manual/fr/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you want regex, do so

```
$str = 'abc<strip><strip><strip>Avoid my tag</strip></strip></strip>def';
echo preg_replace('
     /((<strip>(?=<strip>))*)(<strip>[^<]+<\/strip>)(((?<=<\/strip>)<\/strip>)*)/',
     '\3', $str); // abc<strip>Avoid my tag</strip>def
```

[**Demo and explanation**](https://www.regex101.com/r/eA7gD7/1)

**UPDATE** One more step

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
  '/((<strip>(?=<strip>))*)<strip>([^<]+)<\/strip>(((?<=<\/strip>)<\/strip>)*)/',
  create_function(
    '$matches',
    'return "<strip>".htmlentities($matches[3])."</strip>";'
  ),
  $content
);
```

Comment: That does strip child `<strip>` tags but it doesn't do its main work which is applying htmlentities on other tags inside the parent `<strip>` tag